# Does somebody know about a tool to design filters for DSPIC?

Tags: pic, filter, iir, fir

I have to make a filter with DSPIC33 and I want a program that design the filter (there are a lot), yet export code to DSPIC (in c, any compiler or assembly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microchip sells such software: http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=SW300001

Alternatively if you don't want to pay, you can use any FIR or IIR filter design software you want to come up with your coefficients, implementing the filter on the dsPIC is really easy with microchip's DSP library which is included in the C30 compiler, which I assume your using.

Comment: I'm not using a campiler yet because I want to know in which would be easier to implement the filter. What do you actually mean by "really easy"?

Comment: just check out the documentation for the DSP library on Microchip's website, i'd give ya a link but their site is down for maintainance right now.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to design and simulate your filters and algorithms in matlab and then implement the functions by writing your own C code.  By using matlab you can tune your filters on real data for optimum results and then write your c code based on the initial values.

At some point you will need to consider rounding and errors (for example real filter coefficents are floats in matlab) and you will probably want to implement them as integers on the pic to reduce the overhead of floating point arithmetic.

Once you have written your code and tested it, transfer it back to matlab to see the effects of the rounding errors, and optimise your filter coefficients there.

This may sounds difficult, but in the long term it will give you a few things. Better understanding of the filters, better understanding of the dsPIC architecture and built in hardware (integer multiplier), understanding of rounding errors on the filter coefficents, and most importantly highly optimised code!

It is the optimised code that you really want running on your dsPIC.  You will only be able to acheieve this by iterating between matlab and your c code (perhaps even assembly if you want to getter maximum performance out of the pic).

Answer (score 1):

I thought that matlab had a solution for filter design where you could export to dsPICs. I saw a lot about it, I can look into it later.

#### After Research

Take a look at the [application note that Microchip about it](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MATLAB_Device_Blocks_51771b.pdf). I also found that there are a few notes at http://www.kerhuel.eu/RTWdsPIC/download.html

I cannot guarantee that this will get the job done for you, just trying to show you rapid prototyping options.

Comment: You say that I can export C code directly from matlab?

Comment: Yes you can export to ANSI C from Matlab, however i don't know of a compiler for the dsPIC that is actually ANSI compliant.

Comment: More information has been added to my answer.

Comment: The gcc compiler Microchip uses for the dsPIC is supposed to be ANSI-compliant.